# Обработка статей

Tags: android

Куда лучше вставлять большое количество текста в WebView или TextView? И куда вставляется в нормальных приложениях?

p.s. Среди текста присутствуют картинки и видео.

Answer (score 1):

WebView

Comment: @good, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.